# Group By and Sum Quantity by Direction Column

Tags: mysql

Good Day guys is there a way for me to **group by** an item and **sum** its quantity using the **direction column**?

I want to add new column **positive_quantity** (direction are 1, 4, 5)
and **negative_quantity** (direction are 2, 3, 6)

here's my code:

```
SELECT 
    il.warehouse_id,
    w.code as warehouse_code,
    w.name as warehouse_name,
    il.item_id, 
    i.code as item_code,
    i.name as item_name,
    il.lot, 
    il.date_expiry, 
    il.direction,
    il.location_id,
    //SUM(il.qty), as posive_quantity (base on direction 1, 4, 5)
   //SUM(il.qty), as negative_quantity (base on direction 2, 3, 6)
FROM warehouses w
INNER JOIN inventory_logs il
ON w.id = il.warehouse_id
INNER JOIN items as i
ON il.item_id = i.id
WHERE il.location_id IN (1,3) AND il.date_posted BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31'
GROUP BY 
il.warehouse_id,
il.item_id, 
il.lot, 
il.date_expiry, 
il.location_id,
direction
```

[image]

here is my desired output:
[image]

Thank you in advance. I have also tried using temporary table but it gives me error. like using the same temporary error.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional sum:

```
SELECT 
    il.warehouse_id,
    w.code as warehouse_code,
    w.name as warehouse_name,
    il.item_id, 
    i.code as item_code,
    i.name as item_name,
    il.lot, 
    il.date_expiry, 
    il.location_id,
    sum( if( il.direction in (1,4,5), il.qty, 0 ) ) as positive_quantity,
    sum( if( il.direction in (2, 3, 6), il.qty, 0 ) ) as negative_quantity
FROM warehouses w
INNER JOIN inventory_logs il
ON w.id = il.warehouse_id
INNER JOIN items as i
ON il.item_id = i.id
WHERE il.location_id IN (1,3) AND il.date_posted BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-01-31'
GROUP BY 
il.warehouse_id,
il.item_id, 
il.lot, 
il.date_expiry, 
il.location_id,
```

Btw, your images dot match with the query. It is always best to post the question as text instead of an image, preferably as an SQLFiddle.